# In Django, how do I access request variable when validating password?

Tags: python, django

In Django I need to create a custom password validator which needs to read from the DB to fetch password policy configuration. To do this I need the client ID which is usually embedded in the request variable but in this case, request it is not available. Is there an alternative method to achieve this?

```
class MinimumLengthValidator:
    """
    Validate whether the password is of a minimum length.
    """
    def __init__(self, min_length=8):
        self.min_length = min_length
        #get minimum length from client config here, typically request.client.config.password_min_length e.g. value is 10
```

Comment: From what I can gather, you can get the value of `request.client.config.password_min_length` or the client_id when request is avaialable, and pass it down the chain till you get to the init function in the validator.

Comment: thanks @ybl I understand what you mean but don't know how to execute your suggestion without changing a load of django.contrib files...?

Comment: Well, you did not show how your current setup is implementing user registration. Do you use django User CRUD without any modification?

Comment: Hi @Tarquinius I changed my settings.py
`AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    ...
    {
        #'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        'NAME': 'myapp.auth.validators.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    ...
]`
then copied the standard MinimumLengthValidator.py to myapp/auth/validators/ so I can bespoke it, this is where I got stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: You'll find everything here: [Integrating validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/passwords/#integrating-validation)

Long answer: 
I think the most common way is having a custom User model anyways. Meaning having your "own" User model which is subclassed from `AbstractUser`. There you can overwrite fields, add fields and methods. Fine. Then it totally makes sense to create a User via a `ModelForm` off that User model. Therefore, starting from your view, you could pass the client ID to the `__init__()` method of mentioned `ModelForm` and "pass it down the chain" as @ybl suggested.

But it seems like your project is running entirely on `django.contrib.auth` with no modification at all to the User model. Hence you are right at saying that above solution is "a lot" just for adding one validator. (Most likely though you are going to add a custom user model anyways in the future [(more info)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project), so consider that option).

Write your [custom validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/passwords/#writing-your-own-validator):

```py
class CustomValidator:
    def __init__(self, client_id, pw_config):
        self.client_id = client_id
        self.pw_config = pw_config

    def validate(self, user=None):
        if self.client_id != xx and self.pw_config != xx:
            raise ValidationError(
                "pw not valid", 
                code='clientID_not_pwConfig',
                params={'pw_config': self.pw_config, 'client_id': self.client_id},
            )
        # in case pw is valid return None


    def get_help_text(self):
        return _(
            f"Your {self.client_id} does not match pw_config"
        )
```

Then in your view (resources linked as "short answer" above):

```py
from django.contrib.auth.password_validation import get_password_validators, validate_password


def your_view(request):
    client_id = get_client_id()
    pw_config = get_pw_config()
    standard_validators = get_password_validators(settings.AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS)
    custom_validator = CustomValidator(client_id, pw_config)
    all_validators = standard_validators + [custom_validator]
    
    if validate_password(
        password,  # replace to your needs
        user=None,  # replace to your needs
        password_validators=all_validators
    ) is not None:
        # your pw is valid
    else:
        # your pw is not valid
```